# Photoshop grid not vertical/horizontal?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, grids

This seems like a bizarre question to have to ask - why are my grid lines not perfectly horizontal and vertical?

[image: grid lines]

Comment: Is your monitor level?

Comment: @mayersdesignm in the image you can see that it's rotated. (Not the monitor)

Comment: @WELZ I think it was a joke (I hope it was)

Answer (score 3):

Ah... It was this - the whole canvas got tilted somehow.

https://forums.adobe.com/thread/2410631

---

To correct the rotation...

- Select the **Rotate View Tool** (<sub>[image]</sub>)
- then click the **Reset View** button (<sub>[image]</sub>) on the **Control Bar** across the top of the screen.